# Using "while (x || y)" Loop in Java

Tags: java, bluej

I have a project for my AP Compsci class in which we are required to input the cost of an item from a soda machine and return the change for the amount paid.

I'm having a bit of problem with the input, however; I am using a while loop to ensure that the input is a double, and that the value for the amount paid is greater than or equal to the cost. *When I test this out, it seems that the I have to enter the amount paid multiple times in order for it to be scanned (see lines 23-30).*

I have tried moving the "scan.next()" to different places within the loop, as well as changing the "scan.next()" to a "scan.nextLine" but both have just introduced more problems. Does anyone happen to know a way that I can check if the input is either not a double or less than the cost, and if so prompt the user to input the value again? I've pasted my code below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Sodamachine
{
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("SODA MACHINE: V1.2");
    System.out.println("Input the cost of the soda can and the amount you put in and your change will");
    System.out.println("be output.");

    System.out.print("\nEnter cost of purchase below:\n$");
    while (! scan.hasNextDouble())
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR: Input was not a real number.");
        System.out.print("Enter cost of purchase below:\n$");
        scan.nextLine();
    }
    double cost = scan.nextDouble();

    //this is where the problem starts

    System.out.print("Enter amount paid below:\n$");
    while ((! scan.hasNextDouble()) || (scan.nextDouble() < cost))
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR: Improper input.");
        System.out.print("Enter amount paid below:\n$");
        scan.next();
    }
    double paid = scan.nextDouble(); 
}
}
```

Comment: You're double scanning some of the time. You'll have to rewrite that in a way where you only call `next()` once per input.

Comment: Try to get the input as a string and then you can do all the checks you want on it (e.g. if it is a double) without having to prompt the user again.

Answer (score 0):

Please try my very basic and similar solution.

Requirements: totalCost and totalPaid values have to be DOUBLE variables.
In case those variables are not DOUBLE, the program stops and you should run it again (of course you can add a loop of other logic and call totalCost and totalPaid many times).

Basic assumption of my solution: totalPaid > totalCost.

Of course you can change and improve my code. This solution is only an idea how your problem can be solved.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("SODA MACHINE: V1.2");
    System.out.println("Input the cost of the soda can and the amount you put in and your change will");
    System.out.println("be output.");

    double totalCost = 0.0;

    System.out.print("\nEnter cost of purchase below:\n$");
    try{
        totalCost = scan.nextDouble();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR: Input was not a real number - please provide DOUBLE value.");
        System.exit(0);
    }               

    System.out.print("Enter amount paid below:\n$");

    double totalPaid = 0.0;

    try{
        totalPaid = scan.nextDouble();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR: Input was not a real number - please provide DOUBLE value.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    System.out.println("Change:\n$" + (totalPaid - totalCost));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to avoid scanning multiple times in the while loop.Suppose your cost is 100 and paid is 90. So your while loop is going to go

scan.nextDouble() < cost)   <-- first scan, which is less than cost,

scan.next();   <-- Second scan.

scan.nextDouble() < cost)  <-- Back to the while loop condition and you have an extra scan!

double paid = scan.nextDouble();  <-- And when you exit the while loop, you have another extra scan!

Ideally, you scan once, and if your conditions are not met, scan again for the new input.

```
    //method to check if String can be converted to Double
    public static boolean isDouble(String input){
        try{
            Double.parseDouble(input);
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    String paid = scan.next(); //scan once

    //while not double or paid less than cost, scan again
    while (!isDouble(paid) || (Double.parseDouble(paid) < cost) ){
        System.out.println("Wrong paid number");
        paid = scan.next();
    }

    double paidDouble = Double.parseDouble(paid);
```